# Django mysql count distinct gives different result to postgres

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, orm

I'm trying to count distinct string values for a fitered set of results in a django query against a mysql database versus the same data in a postgres database. However, I'm getting really confusing results.

In the code below, NewOrder represents queries against the same data in a postgres database, and OldOrder is the same data in a MYSQL instance.

( In the old database, completed orders had status=1, in the new DB complete status = 'Complete'. In both the 'email' field is the same )

```
OldOrder.objects.filter(status=1).count()
6751

NewOrder.objects.filter(status='Complete').count()
6751

OldOrder.objects.filter(status=1).values('email').distinct().count()
3747

NewOrder.objects.filter(status='Complete').values('email').distinct().count()
3825

print NewOrder.objects.filter(status='Complete').values('email').distinct().query
SELECT DISTINCT "order_order"."email" FROM "order_order" WHERE "order_order"."status" = Complete

print OldSale.objects.filter(status=1).values('email').distinct().query
SELECT DISTINCT "order_order"."email" FROM "order_order" WHERE "order_order"."status" = 1
```

And here is where it gets really bizarre

```
new_orders = NewOrder.objects.filter(status='Complete').values_list('email', flat=True)
len(set(new_orders))
3825

old_orders = OldOrder.objects.filter(status=1).values_list('email',flat=True)
len(set(old_orders))
3825
```

Can anyone explain this discrepancy? And possibly point me as to why results would be different between postgres and mysql? My only guess is a character encoding issue, but I'd expect the results of the python set() to also be different?

Comment: What about handling of letter cases?

Comment: A raw comparison of the emails in both database ( comparing the 2 values_lists in python ) yields no difference, is there a difference in how postgres and mysql would handle case-sensitivity ?

Comment: Is there a way to do a case-insensitive distinct count in django ?

Comment: Sounds like you're probably using a case-insensitive collation in MySQL. There's no equivalent in PostgreSQL; the closest is the `citext` data type, but usually you just compare `lower(...)` of strings, or use `ILIKE` for pattern matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're probably using a case-insensitive collation in MySQL. There's no equivalent in PostgreSQL; the closest is the `citext` data type, but usually you just compare `lower(...)` of strings, or use `ILIKE` for pattern matching.

I don't know how to say it in Django, but I'd see if the count of the set of distinct lowercased email addresses is the same as the old DB.

According to [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/) something like this might work:

```
NewOrder.objects.filter(status='Complete').values(Lower('email')).distinct()
```